# Impossible to test Angular UI Typeahead with Poltergeist and PhantomJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, poltergeist

I'm having a problem testing my typeahead inputs. I'm using Rails, RSpec, Capybara, Angular UI 0.10, AngularJS, Poltergeist. This is my test:

```
create(:user, name: "Test User")
fill_in 'User', with: "Test"
find('#delegations').find('li.active').click
```

If I run it using the Chrome driver, it runs successfully. However, when running with Poltergeist, the suggestion box is not showed, although the server receives the request and returns the users accordingly.

I think that the `fill_in` is triggering `blur` on the field, making the box disappear. I used `Capybara::Screenshot` to see if there was any suggestion showing up, but there wasn't. The input field doesn't even get the focus.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out it really was because Poltergeist triggers the `blur` in `fill_in`. All I had to do was, before filling the typeahead field, execute this script:

```
page.execute_script "$('input[typeahead]').unbind('blur')"
```

This way, UI Typeahead's `blur` event doesn't get called and it thinks it has the focus on the field, rendering the suggestions box accordingly.

In case you are not using JQuery, this script works with AngularJS:

```
elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].hasAttribute('typeahead')) {
    angular.element(elements[i]).unbind('blur');
  }
}
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver. I was struggling with the exact same issue this morning. If we were in prison together, I'd protect you.

Comment: Thanks for the question and the answer. That was doing my head in.

Comment: I'd also give you my bar of soap if you dropped yours.

Comment: Great stuff.  To be clear to future searchers, this technique works on Twitter Typeahead: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ which I believe is what Angular Typeahead uses.